# Trouble installing pg gem

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems, osx-lion

Trying to install the pg gem gives me errors.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p125 built using rbenv/ruby-build. I installed PostgreSQL using the one-click installer. I'm able to connect to the DB using pgAdmin. I'm running out of ideas.

```
% gem install pg                                                                                                                                                                                                      ~
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/sandropadin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg_connection.c:1986: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Users/sandropadin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg_connection.c:2512: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Users/sandropadin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
compiling pg_result.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sandropadin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sandropadin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Where did you get your libssl from? Sounds like you might be trying to mix 32bit and 64bit binaries.

Comment: I think just from using `brew install openssl`

Comment: I think you're correct about mixing the two, but I don't know if it's possible or how to force Homebrew to build openssl as 64-bit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure which of the following steps finally cleared this issue up. But as mu is too short mentioned, the problem was mixing 32bit and 64bit binaries.

- 1st, I installed this [64-bit version of PostgreSQL](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:postgres)
- 2nd, I uninstalled any old Homebrew OpenSSL installation

  > $ brew uninstall openssl
- 3rd, I installed the 64-bit version of OpenSSL with Homebrew

  > $ brew install --64-bit openssl
- Lastly, when installing the pg gem, I changed the LDFLAGS to point to the 64-bit version of OpenSSL

  > $ gem install pg -- --with-ldflags='-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/0.9.8s'

Comment: I must say that I've been struggling to get the `pg` gem to compile on my copy of Lion for about 6 months. Now this answer came along, and I am able to run Rails 3.2 + PostgreSQL like a champ. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me on Mountain Lion, ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]. I used `brew install postgresql`, and didn't have openssl already, so just `brew install --64-bit openssl` and then used the LDFLAGS it supplied.

Comment: works great, except the version of openssl has moved on (now at 1.0.1c).  A user will need to cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/ and run `ls` to see their version number