# install curb gem on Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm getting this error when trying to install curb on my Mac:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o curb_core.bundle curb.o curb_easy.o curb_errors.o curb_multi.o curb_postfield.o curb_upload.o -L. -L/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib -L/Users/user/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  -lcurl
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [curb_core.bundle] Error 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have Xcode installed? Try also reinstall zlib, openssl and curl

Comment: Yes, I do have Xcode installed. Re suggestions, thanks - will try that.

Comment: @PriteshJ Thanks - that fixed it. Please add as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you need to have 64 bit `openssl`

check this

[Trouble installing pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846900/trouble-installing-pg-gem)