# An error occurred while installing pg (0.15.1) ; PostgreSQL on Mac Installation Error: no pg_config, gem native extension build failure

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, pg

I have OSX 10.6.8 and am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.2 on my device. I used the graphical installer available on their [website](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/), and set up the software, without using stack builder at the end to additionally configure other functions.

When I load my Rails file and `bundle install` I encounter the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Using atomic (1.1.10) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0)  
Using formatador (0.2.4) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.3) 
Using rb-inotify (0.9.0) 
Using rb-kqueue (0.2.0) 
Using listen (1.2.2) 
Using lumberjack (1.0.4) 
Using method_source (0.8.1) 
Using slop (3.4.5) 
Using pry (0.9.12.2) 
Using guard (1.8.1) 
Using rspec-core (2.13.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.13.0) 
Using turbolinks (1.2.0) 
Using jquery-turbolinks (1.0.0) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (4.0.3) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using kaminari (0.14.1) 
Using nested_form (0.3.2) 
Installing pg (0.15.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/pg-0.15.1     for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.15.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.15.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config` , all of the error message suggestions I've gotten and the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846900/trouble-installing-pg-gem). I have also tried re-installing Postgres, locating the appropriate config path, and locating the mfmk.log file the error message mentions (but the file doesn't exist on my computer). Furthermore, under my apps/PostgreSQL, there is a "Reload Configuration" application that, when I run, says `Server signaled`.

Anyone know what I should do? I was going to try Homebrew, but I found it quite strange that the installer itself wouldn't be able to produce functioning software.

Comment: The result with `--with-pg-config=...` would be more informative than the result without it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac try:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

This worked for me (The brew installer told me this... gotta love brew)